# Area enclosed by an equipotential curve for an electric dipole on the plane

Tags: calculus, integration, curves

I am currently teaching Physics in an Italian junior high school. Today, while talking about the [electric dipole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole#/media/File:Dipole_Contour.svg) generated by two equal charges in the plane, I was wondering about the following problem:

> Assume that two equal charges are placed in $(-1,0)$ and $(1,0)$.
>
> There is an equipotential curve through the origin, whose equation is
> given by:
> $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}}=2 $$ and
> whose shape is very [lemniscate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate)-like:

[image]

> **Is there a fast&tricky way to compute the area enclosed by such a curve?**

Numerically, it is $\approx 3.09404630427286$.

Comment: I doubt this helps, but the curve strongly resembles a [hippopede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippopede). Mathematica suggests to me that $b=1$ and $a$ is some value near $\dfrac{2}{3}$ (a bit smaller).

Comment: HINT: Guessing .. a conversion to polar coordinates as $ \int r^2 d \theta/2 $ may simplify it.

Comment: @Narasimham: to get what?

Comment: The enclosed area

Comment: May be by using inversion about $ r=1, $ it can be handled as:
Ellipse$ \rightarrow  $Equipotential $ r_1+ r_2 = 2   \rightarrow 1/r_1+ 1/ r_2 = 2 $..;  constant arithmetic $ \rightarrow$  harmonic mean.

Comment: @Narasimham: the integral in polar coordinates is still very hard to compute.

Comment: Oh, sorry for it.. shall try the harmonic simplification..also could inversions be of help?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Indeed it is. Coincidentally, I spent a few hours a couple of days ago seeing if I could crack this problem of yours (how odd that there's suddenly activity in the comment section after all these months at the same time?), and while I made some progress, I stalled out trying to solve a particular quartic equation, which I posted as a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1582630/factoring-the-quartic-leftx2x-1-right-leftx22x-1-right-2sx-left2x) yesterday.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: What you have mentioned in the link is a dipole with opposite charges and what you have written is for a dipole with the same charges! :)

Comment: @H.R.: well, you are right, but I think that is not the main issue here :)

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio: Just wanted to notice that! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider following parametrization of the first quadrant of the $(x,y)$ plane:

$$[1,\infty) \times [0,1] \ni (u,v) 
\quad\mapsto\quad (x,y) \in [0,\infty)^2 \quad\text{s.t.}\quad
\begin{cases}
r_1 &= \sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2} = u+v\\
r_2 &= \sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2} = u-v
\end{cases}$$
In this parametrization, the area element is given by
$$dx \wedge dy = -\omega\quad\text{ where }\quad \omega \stackrel{def}{=} \frac{u^2-v^2}{\sqrt{(u^2-1)(1-v^2)}} du \wedge dv$$
Let $D$ be the region in $(u,v)$ plane corresponds to the dipole in first quadrant. Its boundary $\partial D$ consists of 3 pieces

1. $C_1$ : a curve start at $(1,0)$, end at $(\phi,1)$ where $\phi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the Golden ratio.
   $$[1,\phi] \in t \quad\mapsto\quad (u,v) = \left(t,\sqrt{t(t-1)}\right) \in [1,\infty) \times [0,1]$$
2. $C_2$ : a line segment from $(\phi,1)$ to $(1,1)$.
3. $C_3$ : a line segment from $(1,1)$ to $(1,0)$.

Notice $\omega = \frac12 d\Omega$ where
$$\Omega \stackrel{def}{=} \frac{u (u^2 - 1) dv - v(1-v^2) du}{\sqrt{(u^2-1)(1-v^2)}}$$
The area $\mathcal{A}$ we seek equals to
$$\mathcal{A} = 4 \int_D \omega = 2\int_{\partial D}\Omega = 2\left(\int_{C_1} + \int_{C_2} + \int_{C_3}\right) \Omega$$

Introduce another parametrization for the region $[1,\infty) \times [0,1]$ in the $(u,v)$ plane:

$$[0,\infty) \times [0,\pi] \ni (\rho,\eta) \quad\mapsto\quad (u,v) = (\cosh\rho,\cos\eta) \in [1,\infty) \times [0,1]$$

One can use this to verify the line segments $C_2$ and $C_3$ contribute nothing to $\mathcal{A}$. As a result,

$$\mathcal{A} = 2\int_{C_1} \Omega 
= 2\int_{C_1} \left(u\sqrt{\frac{u^2-1}{1-v^2}} dv - v\sqrt{\frac{1-v^2}{u^2-1}} du\right)$$

Since $v^2 = u(u-1)$ on curve $C_1$, we can transform the $1^{st}$ piece of the integrand as
$$\begin{align}
u\sqrt{\frac{u^2-1}{1-v^2}} dv
&= \sqrt{\frac{u(u+1)}{1-v^2}} vdv
= \sqrt{u(u+1)} d(-\sqrt{1-v^2})\\
&= -d \sqrt{u(u+1)(1-v^2)} + \sqrt{1-v^2}d\sqrt{u(u+1)}\\
&= -d\sqrt{u(u+1)(1-v^2)} + \sqrt{\color{red}{\frac{1-v^2}{u(u+1)}}}\left(\color{red}{u} + \frac12\right) du
\end{align}
$$
Notice the piece in red can be rewritten as
$\displaystyle\;\sqrt{\frac{u(1-v^2)}{u+1}} du = v\sqrt{\frac{1-v^2}{u^2-1}} du\;$
which is nothing but the $2^{nd}$ piece. This leads to

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{A} 
&= -2 \left[\sqrt{u(u+1)(1-v^2)}\right]_{(u,v) = (1,0)}^{(\phi,1)} +  \int_{C_1} \sqrt{\frac{1-v^2}{u(u+1)}} du\\
&= \sqrt{8} + \int_1^\phi \sqrt{\frac{1+u-u^2}{u(u+1)}} du \tag{*1}
\end{align}
$$

As a double check, one can throw following command to wolfram alpha,

`Sqrt[8]+Integrate[Sqrt[(1+u-u^2)/(u*(u+1))],{u,1,GoldenRatio}]`

to evaluate in $(*1)$ numerically. WA returns
$$\mathcal{A} \approx 
3.0940463058814386237217800770286020796565427678...$$
a number matching what has been stated on question.

This is as far as I can get. I hope someone can further simplify the integral in $(*1)$. Please note that WA do know how to compute the anti-derivative for the integral at $(*1)$. It is a page long expression in terms of elliptic integrals
and I won't reproduce it here.

Comment: I think your $(* 1)$ is the best form we can hope for, so I am accepting your answer. Nice work.

Comment: Can I ask that what was your motivation, behind these change of variable? :) Specially, the first one in $u$ and $v$.

Comment: @H.R. I start with coordinates $r_1, r_2$ like you. The domain of parametrization isn't that easy to describe under them. After I switch to use $u,v$, the boundary of the domain get aligned with the axses. Since I intend to evaluate the double integral by first converting it to a line integral, an axis aligned contour simplifies a lot of stuff. Not to mention under $u,v$, the area element is much simpler (this is probably because the $uv$-coordinate system is an orthogonal one).

Comment: @achillehui I managed to make some progress on that elliptic integral in (*1), reducing it to a mixed sum of complete and incomplete standard elliptic integrals. I have hopes of simplifying it further, and if you have any suggestions there then I'm all ears. Cheers!

Answer (score 7):

Consider this post an appendix to @achillehui's brilliant solution, which arrives at the following elliptic integral for the overall area:

> $$\mathcal{A}=\sqrt{8}+\int_{1}^{\phi}\sqrt{\frac{1+x-x^{2}}{x\left(1+x\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}x=:\sqrt{8}+\mathcal{B},\tag{1}$$

where as usual $\phi$ denotes the golden ratio. I found this problem extremely interesting and just couldn't resist leaving that last integral unevaluated. The work below addresses the nuts and bolts of evaluating this elliptic integral as a particular case of a more general integral.

---

For real parameters $a,b,c,d,z\in\mathbb{R}\land d<c<b\le z<a$, define $\mathcal{E}{\left(a,b,c,d;z\right)}$ via the integral

> $$\mathcal{E}{\left(a,b,c,d;z\right)}:=\int_{z}^{a}\sqrt{\frac{\left(a-x\right)\left(x-c\right)}{\left(x-b\right)\left(x-d\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}x.\tag{2}$$

For convenience we define ahead of time the auxiliary parameters

$$\begin{cases}
&\theta:=\arcsin{\left(\sqrt{\frac{\left(a-c\right)\left(z-b\right)}{\left(a-b\right)\left(z-c\right)}}\right)},\\
&\kappa:=\sqrt{\frac{\left(a-b\right)\left(c-d\right)}{\left(a-c\right)\left(b-d\right)}},\\
&\nu:=\frac{a-b}{a-c}.\tag{3}\\
\end{cases}$$

The key to putting the elliptic integral $\mathcal{E}$ into something more closely resembling standard form the "magic" quadratic transformation,

$$\sqrt{\frac{\left(a-c\right)\left(x-b\right)}{\left(a-b\right)\left(x-c\right)}}=y\implies x=\frac{b\left(a-c\right)-c\left(a-b\right)y^{2}}{\left(a-c\right)-\left(a-b\right)y^{2}}.\tag{4}$$

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}{\left(a,b,c,d;z\right)}
&=\int_{z}^{a}\sqrt{\frac{\left(a-x\right)\left(x-c\right)}{\left(x-b\right)\left(x-d\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{\sin{\theta}}^{1}\frac{2\left(a-b\right)\left(b-c\right)y}{\left(a-c\right)\left(1-\nu y^{2}\right)^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{\left(a-c\right)\left(1-y^{2}\right)}{\left(b-d\right)y^{2}\left(1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\frac{2\left(a-b\right)\left(b-c\right)}{\sqrt{\left(a-c\right)\left(b-d\right)}}\int_{\sin{\theta}}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\left(1-\nu y^{2}\right)^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1-y^{2}}{1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}}}.\tag{5}\\
\end{align}$$

Defining another auxiliary function,

$$f{\left(\kappa,\nu;\theta\right)}:=\int_{\sin{\theta}}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\left(1-\nu y^{2}\right)^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1-y^{2}}{1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}}},\tag{6}$$

we then find,

$$\begin{align}
f{\left(\kappa,\nu;\theta\right)}
&=\int_{\sin{\theta}}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\left(1-\nu y^{2}\right)^{2}}\sqrt{\frac{1-y^{2}}{1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}}}\\
&=\int_{\sin{\theta}}^{1}\frac{1-y^{2}}{\left(1-\nu y^{2}\right)^{2}}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{\left(1-y^{2}\right)\left(1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}\right)}}\\
&=\int_{\sin{\theta}}^{1}\frac{\left(1-\nu y^{2}\right)+\left(\nu y^{2}-y^{2}\right)}{\left(1-\nu y^{2}\right)^{2}}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{\left(1-y^{2}\right)\left(1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}\right)}}\\
&=\int_{\sin{\theta}}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\left(1-\nu y^{2}\right)\sqrt{\left(1-y^{2}\right)\left(1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}\right)}}\\
&~~~~~-\left(1-\nu\right)\int_{\sin{\theta}}^{1}\frac{y^{2}}{\left(1-\nu y^{2}\right)^{2}}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{\left(1-y^{2}\right)\left(1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}\right)}}\\
&=\int_{\sin{\theta}}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\left(1-\nu y^{2}\right)\sqrt{\left(1-y^{2}\right)\left(1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}\right)}}\\
&~~~~~-\left(1-\nu\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial\nu}\int_{\sin{\theta}}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\left(1-\nu y^{2}\right)\sqrt{\left(1-y^{2}\right)\left(1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}\right)}}\\
&=\left[1-\left(1-\nu\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial\nu}\right]\int_{\sin{\theta}}^{1}\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\left(1-\nu y^{2}\right)\sqrt{\left(1-y^{2}\right)\left(1-\kappa^{2}y^{2}\right)}}\\
&=\left[1-\left(1-\nu\right)\partial_{\nu}\right]\left[\Pi{\left(\nu,\kappa\right)}-\Pi{\left(\theta,\nu,\kappa\right)}\right].\tag{7}\\
\end{align}$$

Caution: out of force of habit, I use the argument conventions for denoting elliptic integrals that are adopted in Gradshteyn *et. al*, which differs slightly from that of many other common sources (such as an Wolfram-related reference or software).

Using the partial derivative formula

$$\small{\partial_{\nu}\Pi{\left(\theta,\nu,\kappa\right)}=\frac{E{\left(\theta,\kappa\right)}+\frac{\kappa^{2}-\nu}{\nu}F{\left(\theta,\kappa\right)}+\frac{\nu^{2}-\kappa^{2}}{\nu}\Pi{\left(\theta,\nu,\kappa\right)}-\frac{\nu\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}}{2\left(1-\nu\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}}{2\left(\kappa^{2}-\nu\right)\left(\nu-1\right)}},\tag{8}$$

we then find,

$$\begin{align}
f{\left(\kappa,\nu;\theta\right)}
&=\left[1-\left(1-\nu\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial\nu}\right]\left[\Pi{\left(\nu,\kappa\right)}-\Pi{\left(\theta,\nu,\kappa\right)}\right]\\
&=\frac{E{\left(\kappa\right)}+\frac{\kappa^{2}-\nu}{\nu}K{\left(\kappa\right)}+\frac{2\nu\kappa^{2}-\nu^{2}-\kappa^{2}}{\nu}\Pi{\left(\nu,\kappa\right)}}{2\left(\kappa^{2}-\nu\right)}\\
&~~~~~\small{-\frac{E{\left(\theta,\kappa\right)}+\frac{\kappa^{2}-\nu}{\nu}F{\left(\theta,\kappa\right)}+\frac{2\nu\kappa^{2}-\nu^{2}-\kappa^{2}}{\nu}\Pi{\left(\theta,\nu,\kappa\right)}-\frac{\nu\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}}{2\left(1-\nu\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}}{2\left(\kappa^{2}-\nu\right)}}.\\
\end{align}$$

---

Suppose now that $a+c+d=0\land c\ge b-a\land b\le0$. Then, setting $z=a+c$ we have

$$\begin{cases}
&\theta=\arcsin{\left(\sqrt{\frac{\left(a-c\right)\left(a-b+c\right)}{\left(a-b\right)a}}\right)},\\
&\kappa=\sqrt{\frac{\left(a-b\right)\left(a+2c\right)}{\left(a-c\right)\left(a+b+c\right)}},\\
&\nu=\frac{a-b}{a-c}.\\
\end{cases}$$

Also setting $c=1-a\land b=0$, yields

$$\begin{cases}
&\theta=\arcsin{\left(\frac{\sqrt{2a-1}}{a}\right)},\\
&\kappa=\sqrt{\frac{a\left(2-a\right)}{2a-1}},\\
&\nu=\frac{a}{2a-1}.\\
\end{cases}$$

Under these conditions, we can make the simplifications

$$\begin{align}
f{\left(\kappa,\nu;\theta\right)}
&=\frac{E{\left(\kappa\right)}+\frac{\kappa^{2}-\nu}{\nu}K{\left(\kappa\right)}+\frac{2\nu\kappa^{2}-\nu^{2}-\kappa^{2}}{\nu}\Pi{\left(\nu,\kappa\right)}}{2\left(\kappa^{2}-\nu\right)}\\
&~~~~~\small{-\frac{E{\left(\theta,\kappa\right)}+\frac{\kappa^{2}-\nu}{\nu}F{\left(\theta,\kappa\right)}+\frac{2\nu\kappa^{2}-\nu^{2}-\kappa^{2}}{\nu}\Pi{\left(\theta,\nu,\kappa\right)}-\frac{\nu\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}}{2\left(1-\nu\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}}{2\left(\kappa^{2}-\nu\right)}}\\
&=\frac{K{\left(\kappa\right)}-F{\left(\theta,\kappa\right)}}{2\nu}+\frac{\Pi{\left(\nu,\kappa\right)}-\Pi{\left(\theta,\nu,\kappa\right)}}{a}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{E{\left(\kappa\right)}-E{\left(\theta,\kappa\right)}}{2\left(\kappa^{2}-\nu\right)}+\frac{\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}\sqrt{1-\kappa^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}}{4\left(1-a\right)\left(1-\nu\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\right)}\\
&=\frac{\left(2a-1\right)\left[K{\left(\kappa\right)}-F{\left(\theta,\kappa\right)}\right]}{2a}+\frac{\Pi{\left(\nu,\kappa\right)}-\Pi{\left(\theta,\nu,\kappa\right)}}{a}\\
&~~~~~-\frac{\left(2a-1\right)\left[E{\left(\kappa\right)}-E{\left(\theta,\kappa\right)}\right]}{2a\left(a-1\right)}-\frac{1}{a}\sqrt{\frac{2a-1}{2a\left(a-1\right)}}.\\
\end{align}$$

Thus, for $1<a<2$ we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{E}{\left(a,0,1-a,-1;1\right)}
&=\frac{2a\left(a-1\right)}{\sqrt{2a-1}}\,f{\left(\kappa,\nu;\theta\right)}\\
&=\left(a-1\right)\sqrt{2a-1}\left[K{\left(\kappa\right)}-F{\left(\theta,\kappa\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\sqrt{2a-1}\left[E{\left(\kappa\right)}-E{\left(\theta,\kappa\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2\left(a-1\right)\left[\Pi{\left(\nu,\kappa\right)}-\Pi{\left(\theta,\nu,\kappa\right)}\right]}{\sqrt{2a-1}}\\
&~~~~~-\sqrt{\frac{2\left(a-1\right)}{a}}.\tag{9}\\
\end{align}$$

---

Now, the particular case we're interested in is when $a$ takes the value of the golden ratio, $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, defined of course by the classical condition,

$$\phi=\frac{1}{\phi-1};~~~\small{\phi>0}.$$

A constant associated with $\phi$ is the so-called golden ratio conjugate,

$$\Phi:=\frac{1}{\phi}.$$

We finally obtain a closed form for the quantity $\mathcal{B}$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}
\mathcal{B}
&=\mathcal{E}{\left(\phi,0,1-\phi,-1;1\right)}\\
&=\mathcal{E}{\left(\phi,0,-\Phi,-1;1\right)}\\
&=\left(\phi-1\right)\sqrt{2\phi-1}\left[K{\left(\kappa\right)}-F{\left(\theta,\kappa\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~-\sqrt{2\phi-1}\left[E{\left(\kappa\right)}-E{\left(\theta,\kappa\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2\left(\phi-1\right)\left[\Pi{\left(\nu,\kappa\right)}-\Pi{\left(\theta,\nu,\kappa\right)}\right]}{\sqrt{2\phi-1}}\\
&~~~~~-\sqrt{\frac{2\left(\phi-1\right)}{\phi}}\\
&=\Phi\sqrt[4]{5}\left[K{\left(\kappa\right)}-F{\left(\theta,\kappa\right)}\right]-\sqrt[4]{5}\left[E{\left(\kappa\right)}-E{\left(\theta,\kappa\right)}\right]\\
&~~~~~+\frac{2\Phi}{\sqrt[4]{5}}\left[\Pi{\left(\nu,\kappa\right)}-\Pi{\left(\theta,\nu,\kappa\right)}\right]-\Phi\sqrt{2},\tag{10a}\\
\end{align}$$

where

$$\begin{cases}
&\theta=\arcsin{\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\phi-1}}{\phi}\right)},\\
&\kappa=\sqrt{\frac{\phi\left(2-\phi\right)}{2\phi-1}},\\
&\nu=\frac{\phi}{2\phi-1}.\tag{10b}\\
\end{cases}$$

Result $(10)$ above is potentially a place to step, but the six separate elliptic integral terms make the expression too cumbersome to fool with if we don't have too. Since each elliptic integral term has the same elliptic modulus $\kappa$, simplification seems very likely. I'll update my response if I make any progress towards a simplified final value.

Answer (score 5):

At the first step, I will introduce a proper curve linear coordinates for this problem. This will help to construct the integral for area. We can write the equation of these equi-potential curves as

$$\frac{1}{r_1}+\frac{1}{r_2}=C \tag{1}$$

where $C$ is some real constant and $r_1$ and $r_2$ are defined as

$$r_1=\sqrt{(x-a)^2+y^2} \\
r_2=\sqrt{(x+a)^2+y^2} \tag{2}$$

where $2a$ is the distance between the two like charges on the $x$-axis placed at $x=a$ and $x=-a$. Equation $(2)$ is introducing a new curve-linear coordinates $(r_1,r_2)$ which is called the **two-center bipolar coordinates**. The geometric interpretation is easy as it just describes the coordinates of a point in $xy$ plane via the distance of that point through two other points which are called the **centers**. You can take look at [this link in WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-center_bipolar_coordinates) or [this post on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346696/how-to-handle-two-center-bipolar-coordinates). However, they doesn't contain that much information.

[image]

Then we find $x$ and $y$ from equations in $(2)$ in terms of $r_1$ and $r_2$. For this purpose, subtract and add the equations in $(4)$ to get

$$\begin{align}
r_2^2-r_1^2&=4ax \\
r_2^2+r_1^2&=2(x^2+y^2+a^2) 
\end{align}
\tag{3}$$

after some simplifications, $x$ and $y$ in terms of $r_1$ an $r_2$ will be

$$
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{1}{4a} (r_{2}^{2}-r_{1}^{2})\\
y &= \pm \frac{1}{4a} \left( \sqrt{16 a^2 r_{2}^{2}-(r_{2}^{2}-r_{1}^{2}+4a^2)^2} \right)
\end{align} 
\tag{4}$$

For a given $(r_1,r_2)$ we will find two pairs $(x,y)$ and $(x,-y)$. It is evident from the above picture that why this happens.

The next step will be the construction of the integral for area. We set $C=2a=2$ and find the intersection of the $\infty$ shaped curve with the $x$-axis

$$y=0 \qquad \to \qquad \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2}}=2 \qquad \to \qquad x=-\phi,0,\phi \tag{5}$$

where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ is the golden ratio number. So according to $(1)$, $(4)$, and $(5)$ the parametric equations of the curve in the **second quadrant** of $xy$ plane will be

$$
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{1}{4} \left(r_{2}^{2}-\left(\frac{r_2}{2r_2-1}\right)^{2}\right)\\
y &= \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{16 r_{2}^{2}-\left(r_{2}^{2}-\left(\frac{r_2}{2r_2-1}\right)^{2}+4\right)^2} 
\end{align}  
\qquad \qquad \phi-1 \le r_2 \le 1  
\tag{6}$$

[image]

Finally, the integral to be evaluated for the area will be

$$\begin{align}
\text{Area} &=4 \int_{-\phi}^{0} y dx \\
&=4 \int_{\phi-1}^{1}y \frac{dx}{dr_2}dr_2 \\
&= \int_{\phi-1}^{1} \sqrt{16 r_{2}^{2}-\left(r_{2}^{2}-\left(\frac{r_2}{2r_2-1}\right)^{2}+4\right)^2} \left(\frac{r_2}{2}-\frac{r_2}{2(2r_2-1)^2}+\frac{r_{2}^{2}}{(2r_2-1)^3}\right) dr_2
\end{align}$$

The numerical value of area up to fifty digits is

$$\text{Area}=3.0940463058814386237217800770286020796565427678113$$

as stated in the question. However, finding a tricky way to evaluate the definite integral of the area in a closed form should be investigated. I did the computations in [this MAPLE file](http://pc.cd/EYcrtalK) which may be useful for anyone who reads this post.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio: Can I ask that what was your approach to find the numerical value of the area? :)

Comment: The brutal way: I solved $\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}}=2$ with respect to $y$, getting a horrible function that I submitted to Mathematica for numerical integration.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another method based on the curve-linear coordinates introduced by *Achille Hui*. He introduced the following change of variables

$$\begin{align}
\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2} &= u+v\\
\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2} &= u-v
\end{align} \tag{1}$$

Then solving for $x$ and $y$ we shall get

$$\begin{align}
x &= u v\\
y &= \pm \sqrt{-(u^2-1)(v^2-1)}
\end{align} \tag{2}$$

required that

$$-(u^2-1)(v^2-1) \ge 0 \tag{3}$$

It does not look familiar but in fact it is! Taking into account the equations $(2)$ and $(3)$, we can consider the following as a parameterization for the **first quadrant** of the $xy$ plane

$$\boxed{
\begin{array}{}
x=uv & & 1 \le u \lt \infty \\
y=\sqrt{-(u^2-1)(v^2-1)} &  & 0 \le v \le 1
\end{array}} \tag{4}$$

I tried to draw the coordinate curves of this curve-linear coordinates and I just noticed that it is exactly the same as the **Elliptic Coordinates** and nothing else! You can show this analytically by the change of variables

$$\begin{align}
u &= \cosh p \\
v &= \cos q
\end{align} \tag{5}$$

I leave the further details in this avenue to the reader.

[image]

Let us go back to the problem of calculating the area. The equation of the $\infty$ curve was

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2+y^2}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+y^2}}=2 \tag{6}$$

so combining $(1)$ and $(6)$ leads to

$$v=\pm \sqrt{u^2-u} \tag{7}$$

and hence the **parametric equation** of the $\infty$ curve in the first quadrant by considering $(4)$ and $(7)$ will be

$$\boxed{
\begin{array}{}
x=u\sqrt{u^2-u} & & 1 \le u \lt \phi \\
y=\sqrt{-(u^2-1)(u^2-u-1)} 
\end{array}} 
\tag{8}$$

and finally the integral for the area is

$$\begin{align}
\text{Area} &=4 \int_{0}^{\phi} y dx \\
&=4 \int_{1}^{\phi}y \frac{dx}{du}du \\
&=2 \int_{1}^{\phi} (4u-3)\sqrt{-u(u+1)(u^2-u-1)}du \\
&\approx 3.09405
\end{align} \tag{9}$$

Comment: @achille hui: Did you know that the curve-linear coordinates you introduced is in fact the **elliptic coordinate**? :) Take a look at my new answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

HINT:

Almost sure area can be evaluated between limits $(u_1,u_2),(v_1,v_2)$ for holomorphic functions of complex variables in conformal maps.

The equipotentials and lines of force form an orthogonal net  of curvilinear rectangle curves (resemble Cassinian Ovals, but different.. one out of which is shown above), and force lines which are all concurrent hyperbolas passing through the pole of same polarity / charge and asymptotic to y-axis. For these $(u,v)$ parameter plots that satisfy Laplace equation all we need before evaluating integral of  area is to identify limits of u and v for any oval chosen. (shall upload equation , if it is found in sites e.g. 2d curves.com)

EDIT1:

The closest that I can get to the function is sketched by Mark McClure in another context for  $ f(z)= z^2 (z-1)^3 $:

[Orth Traj to Hyperbolae](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/607436/what-do-polynomials-look-like-in-the-complex-plane)

I think we should choose another complex variable part so that our hyperbolae pass through $ (\pm 1,0)$ instead of $ ( 0,0),(1,0)$ as given above. We are interested in a particular orthogonal trajectory doubly intersecting at origin. Calculation of area may be easier.