# Surface of $(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 = a^2 * (x^2 - y^2)$ using surface integrals

Tags: integration, surfaces

I have to find the surface of  $$(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^2 = a^2(x^2 - y^2)$$ using a surface integral and really have no idea what to do... I would really appreciate it if you could give me an idea.

Comment: hint: cylindrical coordinates will help

Answer (score 2):

To find $S$ may be highly non-trivial: that implicit surface recalls some [equipotential surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_surface#Equipotential_surface_of_point_charges); a similar (just 2d) [question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1262174/area-enclosed-by-an-equipotential-curve-for-an-electric-dipole-on-the-plane) is still unsolved.

Anyway, the section $z=0$ of that surface is a [lemniscate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate), and by setting:
$$ f(x,y) = \sqrt{-(x^2+y^2)+|a|\sqrt{x^2-y^2}} $$
we have:
$$ S = 8\iint_{L}\sqrt{\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)^2+1}\;dx\,dy$$
where $L$ is the region given by $0\leq x\leq a$ and:
$$ 0\leq y\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{-a^2-2x^2+|a|\sqrt{a^2+8x^2}}. $$